# Highlighting text in webview by finding the location of the string in it

Tags: ios, webview

I have a document opened in a webview. The document is also read using the avspeech synthesizer framework. I want to highlight the currently speaking string. Is there any way to do it?

I can only get the currently speaking string's location in the whole input string of avspeechsynthesizer. Is there any way to highlight that string in webview using this location?

I want to draw rectangles on the string, rather than reloading the webview by changing the colour of highlighted text. So its better to find the frame of that string in the webview. Can anybody suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

U need to make bridge from your `iOS` app to the `html`/`javascript` page.

The basic is:
from the iOS app to the html/javascript:

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var x = 5; foo(x); goo(x);"]
```

From the html/javascript u can communicate by redirect which will caught in UIWebView delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

And return NO.

An example, in javascript content make a fake redirect:

```
window.location = "my-bridge#var1#var2;
```

This above line code will trig the UIWebView.

Hope That help.

Comment: Can you explain me with an example code? What should replace foo(x) and goo(x)? I dont know javascript and functions in it.

Comment: That was examples to run foo and goo as your javascript methods.
Take a simple tutorial for javascript (no more then 10 minutes) and do your stuff the JS direction.